# Question about understanding a quote from a book marked as closed. Why?

Tags: discussion

https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/31954/19248

Couldn't understand the reason of closure after reading the help center.

What can I do to make it on topic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's easy to explain.

That book does not appear to be a book about philosophy. It looks more like some sort of self-help guru thing.

[Google Books](https://books.google.com/books/about/Thought_Vibration.html?id=nUxQOQAACAAJ) describes the book as

> Includes: Law of attraction in the thought world; Thought-waves and their power of reproduction; About the mind; Mind building; Secret of the will; How to become immune to injurious thought attraction; Transmutation of negative thought; Law of mental control; Asserting the life force; Training the habit mind; Psychology of the emotions; Developing new brain cells; Attractive power-desire force; Law, not chance.

I haven't read it so I can't say for sure but that doesn't sound like philosophy (i.e., the academic discipline -- or a generous expansion on it).

So I'm not really sure how you could make *that* question or anything fundamentally similar to it on topic.

Comment: Thanks,  my idea about philosophy definition was wrong, it seems.

Comment: It'd help if we could know where you think the help center could be clearer.

Comment: Well, I think,  the definition of philosophy which can be easily  understood by newcomers could be included at the top of help center.

Comment: From google: 
`a theory or attitude that acts as a guiding principle for behaviour.`  with this definition,  why isn't my question on topic?

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius That's a very informal definition of philosophy, which doesn't really correspond to what's relevant here (the academic study of philosophy)